# Redirecting output from an executable, but not all output is redirected?

Tags: windows, redirect

I am experiencing an issue whereby I cannot completely redirect output from an executable.  For discussion, let's say the executable is `printnames.exe`.

If I do `printnames.exe` (without redirection), the following output is displayed in the command window:

```
Adam
Tim
Jesse
Sean
```

However if I do `printnames.exe > myfile.txt`, the command window shows:

```
Tim
Sean
```

...and the contents of `myfile.txt` is:

```
Adam
Jesse
```

How is this possible?  What in the code can cause such behavior?  Shouldn't the redirection operator redirect *all* output?

Comment: Are you only redirecting standard output? You should also redirect standard error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is this possible?

You have two output streams.

> What in the code can cause such behavior?

Writing to standard output and also writing to standard error.

> Shouldn't the redirection operator redirect all output?

No.  Default redirection applies to standard output.

Use `2>` to redirect standard error.

---

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Comment: I figured it out (why I deleted my comment - didn't see yours).  I needed to do "printnames.exe > myfile.txt 2>&1".